# Reconnect VPN after Suspend

Tags: suspend, vpn, automation

I have a VPN configured in Ubuntu and set to autoconnect when the system starts. But when I come back from the suspend state, the VPN is always disconnected and I have to reconnect manually.

Is there a native way to make the VPN connection start again automatically in this transition? If not, is there any kind of script or package that could help me configure this?

Answer (score 3):

With `nm-connection-editor`, in the General tab for the Ethernet/Wireless connection you're using, there should be an option to automatically connect the VPN when the interface is brought up.

Comment: I tried this proposal with Ubuntu 18.04 but I did not see any option to automatically connect the VPN.

Comment: Got it! It is important to go on the settings of the connection you are using and not on the VPN itself settings...